# Remove border from custom wxButton

Tags: c++, button, graphics, wxwidgets

I'm writing a calculator application in C++ using the wxWidgets library.
I'm trying to create my own button class with custom graphics, to avoid the default Windows 10 one. However, there's a gray border around the button that I'm not being able to remove. I've tried applying the wxBORDER_NONE flag to the button, but to no avail.

[image: My custom button]

Here's my code:

gridButton.h

```
#pragma once
#include "wx/wx.h"

enum gbSTYLE {
    NUM,
    OP,
    EXTRA
};


class gridButton : public wxWindow
{
    bool pressed;
    bool hovered;
    wxString text;

    static const int width = 50, height = 50;
    
    wxFont* gbFont = new wxFont(20, wxFONTFAMILY_SWISS, wxFONTSTYLE_NORMAL, 
        wxFONTWEIGHT_LIGHT, false, "Lato");
    // RICORDATI DI CANCELLARE font_Button DALLA CLASSE MAIN QUANDO HAI FINITO

    wxBrush* background;
    wxColour* textColor;

    wxBrush* hoveredBackground;
    wxColour* hoveredTextColor;

    wxBrush* pressedBackground;
    wxColour* pressedTextColor;

public:
    gridButton(wxFrame* parent, wxString text, gbSTYLE style);
    ~gridButton();

    void applyStyle(gbSTYLE style);

    void paintEvent(wxPaintEvent& evt);
    void paintNow();
    void render(wxDC& dc);

    void mouseMoved(wxMouseEvent& evt);
    void mouseDown(wxMouseEvent& evt);
    void mouseWheelMoved(wxMouseEvent& evt);
    void mouseReleased(wxMouseEvent& evt);
    void rightClick(wxMouseEvent& evt);
    void mouseLeftWindow(wxMouseEvent& evt);
    void mouseEnterWindow(wxMouseEvent& evt);
    void keyPressed(wxKeyEvent& evt);
    void keyReleased(wxKeyEvent& evt);

    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
};
```

gridButton.cpp

```
#include "gridButton.h"


BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(gridButton, wxWindow)

    EVT_MOTION(gridButton::mouseMoved)
    EVT_LEFT_DOWN(gridButton::mouseDown)
    EVT_LEFT_UP(gridButton::mouseReleased)
    EVT_RIGHT_DOWN(gridButton::rightClick)
    EVT_ENTER_WINDOW(gridButton::mouseEnterWindow)
    EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW(gridButton::mouseLeftWindow)
    EVT_KEY_DOWN(gridButton::keyPressed)
    EVT_KEY_UP(gridButton::keyReleased)
    EVT_MOUSEWHEEL(gridButton::mouseWheelMoved)

    EVT_PAINT(gridButton::paintEvent)

END_EVENT_TABLE()



// funzione costruttrice
gridButton::gridButton(wxFrame* parent, wxString text, gbSTYLE style)
    : wxWindow(parent, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxFULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE) 
    //wxFULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE per evitare un glitch grafico quando si ridimensiona la finestra
{
    SetMinSize(wxSize(width, height));
    this->text = text;
    
    pressed = false;

    applyStyle(style);
}

// funzione distruttrice
gridButton::~gridButton()
{
    delete gbFont;

    delete background;
    delete textColor;

    delete hoveredBackground;
    delete hoveredTextColor;

    delete pressedBackground;
    delete pressedTextColor;
}

void gridButton::applyStyle(gbSTYLE style)
{
    switch (style)
    {
    default:
        background = new wxBrush(wxColour(255, 255, 255), wxBRUSHSTYLE_SOLID);
        textColor = new wxColour(25, 25, 25);

        hoveredBackground = new wxBrush(wxColour(125, 125, 125), wxBRUSHSTYLE_SOLID);
        hoveredTextColor = new wxColour(0, 0, 0);

        pressedBackground = new wxBrush(wxColour(0, 0, 0), wxBRUSHSTYLE_SOLID);
        pressedTextColor = new wxColour(200, 200, 200);
        break;

    case NUM:
        background = new wxBrush(wxColour(140, 171, 168), wxBRUSHSTYLE_SOLID);
        textColor = new wxColour(209, 221, 220);

        hoveredBackground = new wxBrush(wxColour(125, 125, 125), wxBRUSHSTYLE_SOLID);
        hoveredTextColor = new wxColour(0, 0, 0);

        pressedBackground = new wxBrush(wxColour(70, 85, 84), wxBRUSHSTYLE_SOLID);
        pressedTextColor = new wxColour(162, 170, 169);
        break;
    }
}


//chiamato da EVT_PAINT ogni frame
void gridButton::paintEvent(wxPaintEvent& evt)
{
    wxPaintDC dc(this);
    render(dc);
}
//eseguire un render quando si vuole
void gridButton::paintNow()
{
    wxClientDC dc(this);
    render(dc);
}

//renderizzazione, qui si mette la grafica
void gridButton::render(wxDC& dc)
{
    int w = this->GetSize().GetWidth();
    int h = this->GetSize().GetHeight();

    if (pressed) {
        dc.SetBrush(*pressedBackground);
        dc.SetTextForeground(*pressedTextColor);
    }
    else if (hovered) {
        dc.SetBrush(*hoveredBackground);
        dc.SetTextForeground(*hoveredTextColor);
    }
    else {
        dc.SetBrush(*background);
        dc.SetTextForeground(*textColor);
    }

    dc.DrawRectangle(0, 0, w, h);

    dc.SetFont(*gbFont);
    wxSize textSize = GetTextExtent(text);
    dc.DrawText(text, w / 2 - (textSize.GetWidth()), h / 2 - (textSize.GetHeight()));
}

void gridButton::mouseDown(wxMouseEvent& evt)
{
    pressed = true;
    paintNow();
}
void gridButton::mouseReleased(wxMouseEvent& evt)
{
    pressed = false;
    paintNow();
}
void gridButton::mouseEnterWindow(wxMouseEvent& evt)
{
    hovered = true;
    paintNow();
}
void gridButton::mouseLeftWindow(wxMouseEvent& evt)
{
    hovered = false;
    pressed = false;
    paintNow();
}

// eventi inutilizzati
void gridButton::mouseMoved(wxMouseEvent& evt) {}
void gridButton::mouseWheelMoved(wxMouseEvent& evt) {}
void gridButton::rightClick(wxMouseEvent& evt) {}
void gridButton::keyPressed(wxKeyEvent& evt) {}
void gridButton::keyReleased(wxKeyEvent& evt) {}
```

I'm kind of new to wxWidgets, and any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with "you don't show your paintEvent()"?

Comment: Sorry, I somehow didn't notice `paintEvent()` initially.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the code here, maybe you're leaving gaps/borders in your layout between the buttons? How do you create and position them?

Comment: gridButton* test = new gridButton(this, "(", NUM);
MainGrid->Add(test, 0, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 0);

Comment: Using `wxALL` (border on all sides) with `0` (no border) doesn't make sense, but shouldn't create any border neither. If `MainGrid` is a grid sizer, check that you haven't created it with non-zero "gap" parameters.

Comment: MainGrid = new wxGridSizer(w, h, 0, 0);

Comment: I don't see a problem either.  Using [this code](https://zerobin.net/?d235c0db412e6061#J2ES7eciFF0IQwWKCEI3Am85GEgemGJpK3RvhpKLrEE=) to create a grid of buttons, I get [this layout](https://imgur.com/a/76KyA84).  I don't see the grey gap.  I'm using wxWidgets 3.14 on windows if that matters.

Comment: @iKebab897, what is your colors, brush and pen at the time you call `DrawRectangle()`? And what is the parent color? Do you use panel or you drop everything on the main frame?

Comment: @Igor I dont know what a pen is in wxWidgets. The brush is the one set in the render() function. I drop everything in the main frame, although I use different sizers to layout the app.

Comment: @New Pagodi As of now I only tried inserting a single custom button among the other default wxButton's as a test, if you say that generating a grid of them doesn't cause you my problem, I'm later gonna try replacing all the buttons with my custom class.

Comment: Ok I've tried replacing most of the default buttons in MainGrid with the custom ones, but there's still a clear annoying gray outline. [link](https://pasteboard.co/K3DM34K.png)